# Cómo encontrar y contar las veces que ciertos elementos se repiten dentro de un array y comparar cuales tienen los mismos valores combinados?

Tags: php

Parece algo que ya ha sido consultado, pero busque y no encontré nada que me ayudara, es más complejo que el título, pero trataré de ser concreto: necesito recorrer un array multidimensional de sesión en una cesta de compra en PHP para encontrar si la misma combinación de 3 datos se repiten en un mismo sub-array. Es decir, tengo que detectar si la combinación de la misma fecha, hora y lugar se repiten más de 5 veces.

Ejemplo: el usuario añade un artículo a su cesta solicitando una cantidad de 3 piezas, indicando una fecha, hora y lugar de entrega (12/07/18 - 12:00 hrs - zona centro) que aplica por igual para las 3 piezas de ese artículo. Luego continua añadiendo más artículos y añade otro con una cantidad de 1 pieza y otra fecha, hora y lugar (13/07/18 - 12:00 hrs - zona sur). Finalmente agrega un producto más con una cantidad de 4 piezas (12/07/18 12:00 hrs - zona centro). Como podrán ver la hora siempre es la misma, pero el día y el lugar no (y en ocasiones puede haber productos con todos los datos distintos). Cada producto añadido a la cesta genera un sub-array, entonces lo que busco es que el script identifique los sub-arrays que contengan la combinación del mismo día, hora y lugar que se iteren y me devuelva el número total de piezas solicitadas en las suma de esas iteraciones (que serían 7 en este caso, en dos iteraciones, porque el artículo uno tiene un cantidad de 3 y el tercer artículo tiene una cantidad de 4) y el nombre del esos sub-arrays.

Se necesita es que en un mismo pedido el usuario pueda solicitar varios productos con iguales o distintas condiciones de entrega que tendrán un cargo por envío cada uno, pero que dependiendo de la cantidad total de artículos que tengan mismo día, hora y lugar, la entrega de esos artículos baje su costo o incluso sea gratuita.

No se si me explico, alguien tiene alguna sugerencia de como puedo hacerlo? Lo agradeceré mucho. Saludos!

---

ACTUALIZACIÓN: Les comparto más detalles...

Tengo un array como este

```
$array = Array (

    [usuario] => Admin
    [correo] => correo@sitioweb.mx
    [tipo] => Administrador
    [foto] => avatar.jpg

    [cesta] => Array (
      [TUcB2AdBIxdsF95V] => 3
      [wgY0tsYVGrQ8s1aU] => 1
      [kVO18PlrCt1DqgxJ] => 4
    )

    [TUcB2AdBIxdsF95V] => Array (
      [idProducto] => 5
      [entrega] => 2018/07/12
      [hora] => 12:00
      [ubicacion] => Zona centro
    )

    [wgY0tsYVGrQ8s1aU] => Array (
      [idProducto] => 4
      [entrega] => 2018/07/13
      [hora] => 12:00
      [ubicacion] => Zona sur
    )

    [kVO18PlrCt1DqgxJ] => Array (
      [idProducto] => 6
      [entrega] => 2018/07/12
      [hora] => 12:00
      [ubicacion] => Zona centro
    )

  )
```

Donde el array `cesta` contiene los identificadores de cada ítem y la cantidad de ese producto que se está ordenando. Luego los arrays con el respectivo identificador contienen los detalles de cada ítem.

Acá el `foreach` con el que imprimo la lista de la cesta de compra

```
if (isset($_SESSION['cesta'])) {

    foreach ($_SESSION['cesta'] as $id => $cantidad) {

      $entrega     = $_SESSION[$id]['entrega'];
      $hora        = $_SESSION[$id]['hora'];
      $ubicacion   = $_SESSION[$id]['ubicacion'];

    }
}

<div><span><?php echo $entrega.' '.$hora.' '.$ubicacion ?></span></div>
```

Esto me imprime:

```
2018/07/12 12:00 Av. Zona centro
2018/07/13 12:00 Av. Zona sur
2018/07/12 12:00 Av. Zona centro
```

Ahora, en concreto necesito que el script identifique las dos cadenas que coinciden en esos 3 datos, es decir, la misma fecha con misma hora y lugar (en la práctica pueden ser dos o tres cadenas coincidentes de una combinación y otras dos o tres con otras combinaciones) y que luego sume las cantidades de producto de cada ítem y si este es mayor o igual que 5, que devuelva un booleano verdadero a cada ítem.

Comment: mira puedes ir dividiendo tu mismo los subarray, pues cada uno tienen sus indices. entonces cada vez que se genera una compra o se agregue una. puedes ir dividiendolas en subarray de fechas, para luego simplemente debes hacer una busqueda con los ciclos y condicionales.

Comment: Agradecería que me explicaran el voto negativo, realmente necesito la ayuda con este tema y vaya que pasé mucho tiempo indagando y buscando antes de preguntar. Venir y colocar una pregunta es algo que sólo hago cuando de verdad estoy atorado con la solución, he leído el reglamento de como preguntar, y no veo donde está mi error? Si no desean contestar mi pregunta, está bien, pero si me van a calificar negativo al menos dejen su razón en un comentario... agradeceré el feedback.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/105770)

Comment: @Drewkenobi ¿podrías compartir el código con lo que intentaste y cómo el resultado no fue satisfactorio? ¿recibías algún error?

Comment: No soy yo el del voto negativo, pero me imagino que puede ser porque la pregunta es sobre un problema concreto de programación (encontrar repetidos en un array/subarray) y no se incluye nada de código. Eso hace que la pregunta se pueda considerar muy amplia, lo que hará que las respuestas que obtengas sean más sugerencias o estimaciones en vez de respuestas concretas. Sería ideal si pudieras incluir algo más de información sobre tus arrays y el contenido que tienen, así como lo que hayas intentado y los problemas que den. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información y recomendaciones.

Comment: @Alvaro, muchas gracias por el feedbak. He revisado el "cómo preguntar" desde que me afilié a este foro y podría citar varios renglones del centro de ayuda donde avala que lo que estoy preguntando es válido y que no se requiere un código, es más, no tiene que tratarse de un error en un código. Tu mismo calificas mi pregunta como "un problema concreto de programación" y en [help/on-topic] indica que, si tengo un "problema especifico de programación", estoy en el lugar correcto. Tal vez el título de la pregunta es el que es muy genérico y tal vez eso si amerita el voto negativo. Lo editaré.

Comment: @Alvaro, nuevamente gracias por el comentario. Desde ayer he avanzado un poco. No es tanto que recibiera errores que no pudiera resolver, sino que, al ser esta la primera vez que intento algo así, no tenía ni idea de como y por donde empezar. Actualizaré la pregunta con lo que tengo y a ver que retroalimentación surge. Gracias